# SQL Server deployment using DACPAC resulted into creating table without Foreign Keys

Tags: sql, sql-server, dacpac

I am facing a strange issue,

I have the following SQL table definition,

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ParameterValue]
(
    [ParameterValueID] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1), 
    [ParameterID] INT NULL, 
    [FieldDefinitionID] INT NULL, 
    [ParameterValue] VARCHAR(2000) NULL, 
    [ParameterValueTypeID] SMALLINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
)
GO
-- Constraints and Indexes
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ParameterValue] ADD CONSTRAINT [Pk_ParameterValue_ParameterValueID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED  ([ParameterValueID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ParameterValue] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_ParameterValue_Parameter] FOREIGN KEY ([ParameterID]) REFERENCES [Parameter]([ParameterID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ParameterValue] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_ParameterValue_FieldDefinition] FOREIGN KEY ([FieldDefinitionID]) REFERENCES [FieldDefinition]([FieldDefinitionID])
GO
```

I noticed that in the table creation script, only the Primary key constraint is added; foreign key constraints are missing completely.
So the resultant table is created without the foreign keys.
What is the cause behind this?

Note: SQL Server Version --> 13.0.5103.6

Comment: The `Parameter` and `FieldDefinition` tables aren't schema qualified. Are they in a different schema?

Comment: So they are in a different file, Parameter.sql and FieldDefinition.sql (their respective table definition file like ParameterValue)

Comment: So were their file(s) executed before this one? The tables need to exist before the foreign key constraints can be created.

Comment: Elaborate how exactly you publish this project and share publish.xml or sqlpackage cli parameters